# synchronized selects in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, list, select, synchronize

I need to synchronize two selects, something like when I have a country select and I want to show the states for the country selected in the last select tag, so my case is the following: (its in spanish, sorry)...

the first one is,

```
usuario.select :entidad, options_from_collection_for_select(@entidad,'entidad', 'sigla')
```

and the second select is,

```
usuario.select :agencia, options_from_collection_for_select(@agencia,'agencia', 'nombre')
```

ok, so, I want to display the agencies for the entity selected in the first select, thaaanks for some person who can help me, pleease!

Comment: You can do it with ajax, on change of first select, reload the second one.